# Encriptar ou criptografar?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Qual a palavra correta, *encriptar* ou *criptografar?*

Além disso: *descriptografar, decriptar, descriptar* ou *desencriptar?*

Sempre que preciso utilizar essas palavras em conversas ou documentações, prefiro *encriptar* e *decriptar*, mas sempre fico com aquela pulga atrás da orelha.

Comment: Trabalho com criptografia há mais de 10 anos, e como jargão técnico todas são utilizadas indistintamente em documentos e na fala. São sinônimos. Não posso afirmar o mesmo quanto ao que dizem os dicionários sobre eventuais e sutis diferenças entre elas.

Comment: colocar dentro da cripta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo o [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br) *encriptar* e *criptografar* são sinônimos:

> Significado de Criptografar verbo transitivo direto Converter textos,
>   dados ou qualquer outro tipo de informação explícita para um código
>   secreto, de modo que apenas aqueles que detenham o código sejam
>   capazes de decodificar a informação e acessar o seu conteúdo;
>   encriptar, codificar: é preciso criptografar os dados mais
>   estratégicos antes de os enviar pela rede. Etimologia (origem da
>   palavra criptografar): cripto + grafo + ar.
>
> Sinônimos de Criptografar Criptografar é sinônimo de: **encriptar**

*Decriptar* há no dicionário [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/decriptar/):

> Significado de Decriptar verbo transitivo direto Traduzir ou decifrar
>   mensagens cifradas, encriptadas; decodificar: a chave que se utiliza
>   para encriptar é a mesma utilizada para decriptar a mensagem.

Também achei *desencriptar* no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/desencriptar):

> de·sen·crip·tar - Conjugar (des- + encriptar) verbo transitivo
>   [Informática]  Decifrar dados em código. = DESCODIFICAR ≠ CIFRAR,
>   CRIPTAR, ENCRIPTAR

Porém não achei referências para descriptografar e descriptar. Mesmo que descriptografar é encontrado em textos da [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/te15te69%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Descriptografia é a operação inversa da criptografia. Para a
>   criptografia de chave secreta, você deve saber a chave e o IV que
>   foram usadas para criptografar

Answer (score 4):

***Criptografar*** é consensual e vem em todos os dicionários; já ***encriptar***, neste sentido, vem apenas em alguns, nomeadamente no [Priberam (2)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/encriptar), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/encriptar) (versão digital da Porto Editora) e [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/encriptar/); [Cláudia Pinto na FLiP (associada ao Priberam)](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/791) diz que vem também nos dicionários Aurélio (1999) e Porto Editora (2004); mas não vem, neste sentido, no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/encriptar), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/encriptar/), no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002; não sei se vem no Houaiss de 2009) nem no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001).

No entanto há pelo menos vintes anos que [*encriptar* (Google Books)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=encriptar&num=50&lr=lang_pt&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZm5KN2YHXAhVG1BoKHVxXCoMQpwUIHg&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1), a par de [*criptografar* (Google Books)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt%2Csbd%3A1&tbm=bks&q=criptografar&oq=criptografar&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21691.28893.0.30630.8.7.1.0.0.0.93.540.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.25Mc7xBxBY4), aparece com frequência em livros. A razão do tratamento desigual nos dicionário é que enquanto *criptografar* é uma palavra consagrada há muito tempo, *encriptar* é uma adaptação recente do inglês *encrypt*, que por sua vez é, segundo o [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/search?q=encrypt), um neologismo registado apenas a partir de 1968.

O exemplo de mais antigo que encontrei do verbo *encriptar* foi neste [*Jargão: o dicionário informal dos termos da informática* de 1994](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ENgSAQAAMAAJ&q=encriptar&dq=encriptar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLgb6S0__WAhUFXRoKHT82DIU4MhDoAQjdATAc). *Criptografar* é bem mais antigo. *Cryptographia* já vem no dicionário [Moraes Silva de 1831](https://books.google.pt/books?id=VgxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA494&dq=%22arte%20de%20escrever%20de%20um%20modo%20occulto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS24aQ8v_WAhUC1hoKHenSCRoQ6AEIVjAH#v=onepage&q=%22arte%20de%20escrever%20de%20um%20modo%20occulto%22&f=false), definido como:

> CRYPTOGRAPHIA, s. f. Arte de escrever de um modo occulto e inteligivel a qualquer outra pessoa que não seja aquella, a quem o escripto é dirigido.

O verbo já estava em uso em [1912 (Brazil-ferro-carril)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=p3otAQAAMAAJ&q=cryptographadas&dq=cryptographadas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFtoXJ4f_WAhXTSxoKHabYByYQ6AEIKDAA):

> […] permitte communicar em absoluto segredo noticias e ordens cryptographadas

Agora, a minha previsão é que pelo contacto com o inglês *encryp*, *encriptar* vai continuar em uso, e vai ser uma mera questão de tempo para que apareça em todos os dicionários. Entretanto, como diz na [Cláudia Pinto no artigo da FLiP](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/791), a decisão de usar ou não *encriptar* fica ao critério de cada um. Ela argumenta no entanto que não razão para a oposição e que a palavra é “bem formada”. Aliás, a palavra já existia antigamente, mas apenas com o significado de ‘meter em cripta ou em túmulo’; a [cripta (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cripta) é uma galeria subterrânea existente em algumas igrejas. Mas já o dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 classifica este termo como “antigo”.

Os dicionários apresentam também com o mesmo significado [*cifrar* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cifrar) e [*codificar* (Aulete 4 e 6)](http://www.aulete.com.br/codificar); mas qualquer destas palavras tem também vários outros significados. O Priberam, que parece ser o mais aberto a inovações, indica também [*criptar*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/criptar).

Quanto à operação inversa, no Google Books o mais frequente parecer ser [*decriptar*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt&tbm=bks&q=decriptar&oq=decriptar&gs_l=psy-ab.3...29609.29609.0.30059.1.1.0.0.0.0.14.14.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.wa6Yd5pgmIQ), depois [descriptografar](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt%2Csbd%3A1&tbm=bks&q=descriptografar&oq=descriptografar&gs_l=psy-ab.3...579130.579713.0.580623.3.3.0.0.0.0.165.322.2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.oSQC-fCSv30) e [desencriptar](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt&tbm=bks&q=desencriptar&oq=desencriptar&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19572.20531.0.22221.3.3.0.0.0.0.66.195.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.M6jjk3s6fuM), e o menos frequente, [*descriptar*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt&tbm=bks&q=descriptar&oq=descriptar&gs_l=psy-ab.3...829459.830196.0.830859.2.2.0.0.0.0.166.252.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.4GRY0guLXK8). [*Decriptar* vem no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/decriptar) (que não tem nem *criptar* nem *encriptar*), [*descriptar* no dicionário inglês-português da Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/decrypt) e [*desencriptar* no Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/desencriptar). Em princípio, admitindo a existência de *encriptar*, o falante é livre de criar palavras necessárias por prefixação, seja a partir de *encriptar*, dando *desencriptar*, seja do seu componente *criptar*, dando *decriptar* ou *descriptar*.

Já agora, se precisares de uma palavra para ‘ato de encriptar/criptografar’, a minha preferência vai para ***encriptação***, que encontrei apenas no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/encripta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/encripta%C3%A7%C3%A3o). ***Criptografia*** vem em todos os dicionários, mas sugere mais ‘técnicas, arte de criptografar’ do que ‘ato de criptografar’, e é isso que dizem os dicionários. Poderíamos criar *criptografação* ou *criptografagem*, mas para o meu gosto são demasiado compridas e desajeitadas.